# populate select options using jquery load function, but parameter missing in query string

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

```
<form action="getDepartmentID" method="post">
  <div id=main>
   <select id="depList"name="depList"style="width:190px;"class="selListBox">
    <option value="0">[Please Select]</option>
    <option value="43">Information Technology</option>
    <option value="44">Costing and Budgeting</option>
    <option value="45">Supply Chain</option>
    <option value="61">Marketing</option>
    <option value="62">Financial</option>
    <option value="63">HR</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

on submit , query string contain parameter with value i.e. **?depList=43**

---

When I populate this list using **jquery .load();** function i.e.

```
$('#main').load('ajax/Options.jsp');
```

**Options.jsp**

---

```
   <select id="depList"name="depList"style="width:190px;"class="selListBox">
    <option value="0">[Please Select]</option>
    <option value="43">Information Technology</option>
    <option value="44">Costing and Budgeting</option>
    <option value="45">Supply Chain</option>
    <option value="61">Marketing</option>
    <option value="62">Financial</option>
    <option value="63">HR</option>
   </select>
```

---

it successfully populate but when I press submit after selecting an options, it does not send any parameter, even I use the following

---

```
$("#depList").change(function() {
$('#depList option:selected').attr('checked', 'checked');
 });
```

---

How to resolve this situation?

Comment: You have no submit button in your form.  Are you doing this via ajax?

Comment: @wirey I have submit button, just simple submit !<input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="send" /> like this :)

Comment: and it's inside your form? so you are using the default submit action correct?

Comment: yes! dear .. default @wirey every thing is fine , but the select list that I populate using .load(); create problem only.

Comment: it works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/eG2Bu/

Comment: @wirey When I press send, it vanish. Please display the query string on result. submit work successfully also for me, but no any parameter is in query string of this dynamically populated list.  I also test it by method="get" :)

Comment: Basically it send all other parameter sucessfully @wirey

Comment: @Wirey it seem the issue is in the value not being present when the submit is fired. Presumably the sequence of events is out and the options arent present at the time the submit fires.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form information in the query string upon submit you need to be using GET not POST

```
<form action="getDepartmentID" method="get">
```

Comment: using get we can see the query string on bar, but with with post can see on other page ? I have tested using both get and post .. :)

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor post will not show it, but the param and values still get sent to the url inside the action

Comment: if i use method="get", query string also not contain parameter of dynamically populated select list

Comment: What does the query string look like?